# Get the value of android:ellipsize attribute, in a custom view constructor

Tags: android, attributes, textview, android-custom-view, marquee

How to get the value of the attribute `android:ellipsize` in a custom `View` (that extends `TextView`)?

I tried these ways, but didn't work:

```
Log.d(TAG, attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, "ellipsize", -1));
Log.d(TAG, attrs.getAttributeValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, "ellipsize"));
Log.d(TAG, attrs.getAttributeUnsignedIntValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, "ellipsize", 111));
Log.d(TAG, attrs.getAttributeListValue(ANDROID_NAMESPACE, "ellipsize", new String[] {"x", "marquee"}, -1));
```

---

Note: The `attrs` is the `AttributeSet` (constructor parameter) and `ANDROID_NAMESPACE` is `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getAttributeValue` method works for me in this example (Kotlin):

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.TextView

class Text(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : TextView(context, attrs) {
    init {
        println("ellipsize: " +
                attrs.getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
                        "ellipsize"
                )
        )
    }
}
```

It prints:

`11-20 20:49:18.808 26804-26804/com.package.app I/System.out: ellipsize: 1`

for this view:

```
<com.package.app.Text
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="start" />
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it was returning `null`! I found the reason for the difference: I had set its value in styles (not directly in the element XML tag).